# Make swipable on mobile devices

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to make the following code swipable on mobile devices? The method I am currently using can be found at ohessbert.com/mobile/story.htm

```
<script>
        var links = document.querySelectorAll(".heart");
        var wrapper = document.querySelector("#wrapper");
        var activeLink = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
            var link = links[i];
            link.addEventListener('click', setClickedItem, false);
            link.itemID = i;
            } 
        links[activeLink].classList.add("active");
        function setClickedItem(e) {
        removeActiveLinks();
        var clickedLink = e.target;
        activeLink = clickedLink.itemID;
        changePosition(clickedLink);
        }
        function removeActiveLinks() {
        for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].classList.remove("active");
            }
        }
        function changePosition(link) {
            link.classList.add("active");
            var position = link.getAttribute("data-pos");
            wrapper.style.left = position;
        }
</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "swipeable"?

Comment: Well I want the user to be able to swipe the content in the slider if they choose to on their mobile device opposed to tapping the heart indicators.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Swiper API in your code. It works very well in mobile devices.
http://www.idangero.us/swiper/api/#.VXHjE0Zs5jQ

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.